# invalid preprocessing directive #!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a dynamic configuration for a cpp application and I'm adapting the tutorial. I'm getting the following error in my cfg file. Any insight you have will be appreciated.

error: invalid preprocessing directive #!
2 | #!/usr/bin/env python

I've already tried chmod a+x on the file
python version is 3.8.2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360690/invalid-preprocessing-directive-#!/) by [aselya](https://answers.ros.org/users/58857/aselya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-08-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-09-01**:
Can you please update your question and add a copy of your cfg file? It looks to me like the most likely cause is an improperly formatted first line. Your cfg file should have *only* the following on the first line: `#!/usr/bin/env python`. No extra characters or spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it by removing an accidental space in the file

---

Originally posted by [aselya](https://answers.ros.org/users/58857/aselya/) with karma: 16 on 2020-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0